# Shopware: Generating PDF with default font throws "Cannot find TTF TrueType font file "DejaVuSansMono.ttf""

Tags: mpdf, shopware

I am using Mpdf v7 to generate a PDF file. This is my config:

```
$mpdfConfig =
        [
            'margin_left' => 25,
            'margin_right' => 10,
            'margin_top' => 20,
            'margin_bottom' => 20,
            'format' => 'A4-L',
            'mode' => 'win-1252',
        ];
```

Calling the output to save my pdf throws the following error:

> Cannot find TTF TrueType font file "DejaVuSansMono.ttf" in configured font directories.' in /var/www/html/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Fonts/FontFileFinder.php on line 33

I'm using Shopware 5.5.1 and work with the included mpdf library. Calling the pdf with the following code:

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf($mpdfConfig);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($data);
$mpdf->Output($filename, "D");
```

Why is the DejaVuSansMono.ttf font not found? I do not use this font. Event with defining the `'default_font'` to `'Courier'` I get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Shopware is distributed with a modified version of mPDF with font files stripped (that this is a violation of its licence is another matter).

You have two or three options:

Instantiate mPDF with

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'mode' => 'c'
]);
```

configuration parameter which will use internal PDF fonts only

---

or to download or clone mPDF ([from GitHub](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf)), move the `ttfonts` directory to your project and add the folder to mPDF configuration:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'fontDir' => __DIR__ . '/ttfonts', // or similar
]);
```

---

or you can delete the `vendor` directory in your Shopware installation and recreate it by running `composer install` - that should recreate entire mPDF installatino with all fonts in the vendor directory but may cause other problems - I haven't tested this.